# Como puedo obtener el porcentaje de un campo en Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Recién empiezo con el tema de **Power BI**, y requiero obtener el porcentaje de un valor, en el campo de **Campo 1** esta el 100% y en el campo de **Campo 2** necesito obtener su porcentaje actual para luego mostrarlo en una nueva tarjeta. La nueva tarjeta que obtendría el porcentaje actual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes crear una medida con DAX. Esta medida será simplemente una división que devolverá un número decimal, luego la formateas como porcentaje y la configuras con el número de decimales que quieras.

Aunque hay varios caminos para empezar, puedes ir a "Modelado" y allí "Nueva medida". Aparecerá una barra de fórmulas y escribes:

```
% Medida = DIVIDE(Tabla[Campo 1], TABLA[Campo 2], 0)
```

En vez de hacer la operación de división habitual (mediante /), en DAX se utiliza la función DIVIDE que protege la operación de divisiones por cero. En caso de producirse esta circunstancia, devolverá cero.